# How does one do a system upgrade Ubuntu (Preview) from the MS Store?

Tags: upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Earlier this year, Canonical added an ["Ubuntu (Preview)" version for #WSL to the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P7BDVKVNXZ6), this was back when 22.04 was the current release. The preview is supposed to always be for the latest development version.

The [preview version in the store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P7BDVKVNXZ6) was (is still) 22.10.  22.10 has been out for a month now, and no update to 23.04 is in sight.

I got an update to it from the MS store today (for what, I don't know) and it is still at 22.10.

So, I tried upgrading, the old fashion way, and that didn't work, either.

23.04 is currently in development, with daily live images being released, but I'm still stuck at 22.10 in the MS Store "Preview".

[screenshot of upgrade attempt at bash prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO6AM.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, but Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the *latest* LTS release, and Ubuntu 22.10 (the 2022-October release) is the *latest* released version of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu *lunar* only becomes 23.04 when RC (*Release Candidate*) image is available which isn't scheduled to occur until April 2023 so why would you expect to see 23.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *lunar* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 April 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 April 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284 Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *lunar* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Agree with @guiverc.  If you'd like to repost this on [Super User](https://superuser.com), I'd be glad to provide some guidance.  In the meantime, please see my answer to [How to upgrade Ubuntu packages in WSL alongside Microsoft Store auto-update](https://askubuntu.com/q/1384209/1165986) to understand *why* upgrading the Store app for a WSL distribution does not update any existing, installed distribution.  Thanks!

Comment: @guiverc "*so why would you expect to see 23.04?"*  The OP is correct, at least, that the Ubuntu Preview in the Microsoft Store (posted by Canonical) is labeled as 23.04 (Lunar Lobster).  Yes, it's a daily build (and thus definitely off-topic), but even Canonical [used the *number* 22.10](https://ubuntu.com/blog/explore-whats-in-store-ubuntu-preview-on-wsl) to talk about the Preview well-before it was released.

Comment: @guiverc As linked in my OP, this[1] is the version I'm talking about, please read its description for a better understanding of this.

https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P7BDVKVNXZ6

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm not sure how a daily build is off topic if Canonical offers it in the Microsoft Store., but thanks for otherwise explaining this to others.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds, I don't use WSL nor windows so don't tend to remember much of the official release notices... Scott, please read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic if you don't understand why *development* releases are off-topic on this site (as are ESM/EOSS and EOL releases). They are supported elsewhere (I'm a *development* user myself as I'm involved in QA, but this site isn't tracked for issues/support as everything is done at correct locations inc. bug trackers so hopefully little gets missed)

Comment: @guiverc No worries - I know very few people pay attention to WSL like I do ;-).  On the "off-topic" topic, I'm having second thoughts here.  The Help page you linked to references [this Meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/1165986), which indicates that questions about *How to upgrade* to a development release are acceptable.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I figured it out and have updated my post.  I'm now running 23.04, installed from the Microsoft Store, in WSL.

Comment: @guiverc I figured it out and have updated my post. I'm now running 23.04, installed from the Microsoft Store, in WSL.

Comment: @ScottBeamer As Nmath said, please post a new answer.  However, I will say that I did cover that in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384214/1165986) to the other question I pointed you to.  As I mentioned there, you don't even have to *reinstall* - Just unregister the old one and re-running the configuration stage will do it.

Answer (score 1):

> I got an update to it from the MS store today (for what, I don't know) and it is still at 22.10.

First, for some background, please do read my answer to [How to upgrade Ubuntu packages in WSL alongside Microsoft Store auto-update](https://askubuntu.com/q/1384209/1165986).  That will hopefully answer this part of your question, but to summarize:

*Upgrading the Store app for a WSL distribution does not update any existing, installed distribution.*

Again, all the lengthy explanation and details are in the linked question.

> So, I tried upgrading, the old fashion way, and that didn't work, either.

You don't mention exactly what you tried, but the "old fashion way" *should* work just fine.  Since you are currently on 22.10, you can:

- Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and make sure `Prompt=normal`
- Then `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

That should take you from 22.10 to the development branch.  I've just tested and confirmed on my own 22.10 installation here.